# PHP include content from a separate php file

Tags: php, include

A search form in "search.php" is on the vendor's server and it has been set up so my site can display it. The URL is: http://mysite.com/search.php.

The search result page is on the vendor's server also in a separate file called "result.php". It has also been configured so the URL looks like this: http://mysite.com/result.php.

I would like to insert the "search.php" form in the "result.php" file so users don't have to swtich back and forth between the pages.

I tried:

```
 <?php
 include 'http://mysite.com/search.php';
 ?>
```

It didn't work, and then I realized that I need to set "allow_url_fopen" to yes to use URL in the include statement. This is NOT something I want to do as I read other posts here there is security issue involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can include another server's php file, allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are to get the file output of the designated url, i mean, the final result, you won't be able to use the variables or functions from that script.

try using file_get_contents(), or if you are displaying final results anyway, you could just use an iFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']"./search.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
include __dir__  . "/search.php";
```